# Parsing expression with python: from string to integers

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, split

I was trying to split this string in two numbers using multiple delimeters and re library in python

> Input: "['2 5']"
>
> Output [2,5]

Code:

```
   data = re.split(r"'[ ]'",str(sys.stdin.readlines()))
   print data
   integers = map(int,data)
   print integers
```

I don't understand why this code doesn't work, can you help me, please?

Comment: Your regex matches `' '` string, you have none in your input. See **[your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5tv7SH/1)**.

Comment: what do you mean? I thought I have it after square brackets